# dnsmasq not starting on boot

Tags: networking, systemd-startup

Hey guys so I'm using my RaspberryPi with a 4g dongle as gateway for my wireless AP. The pi is connected to the AP through ethernet eht0 and the external internet comes from the dongle eth1. The dongle connects on boot and the internet works on the pi and other devices on the AP. The problem im having is that it doenst work on boot. I have to connect a screen to the pi and manually start `dnsmasq` on a terminal. Once it starts everything seems to work. I used dhcpcd and dnsmasq with iptables to forward everything from **eth1**(dongle internet) to **eth0** wireless AP connected to the pi via ethernet cable. Is there a solution to the dnsmasq problem?

**dnsmasq.conf**

`no-resolv
server=8.8.8.8 # Use Google DNS
interface=eth0 # Use interface eth0
no-dhcp-interface=eht1
dhcp-range=eth0,10.0.0.20,10.0.0.50,255.0.0.255,24h`

**dhcpcd.conf**

`#Internet interface
interface eth1 # Change to eth1 if using wired adapter
static ip_address=192.168.8.100 # Set the Pi IP address address form eth1 connection
static routers=192.168.8.1 # Eth1 default gateway`

`# Local network
interface eth0
static ip_address=10.0.0.1/24`

I then ran some iptable rules and saved it to /etc/iptables/rules.v4

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4`

on boot all i have to do is run `dnsmasq` as root in a terminal. Is there a way I can check dnsmasq and make sure its running and run the command dnsmasq otherwise?

`uname -a` outputs:Linux raspberrypi 4.19.75-v7+ #1270 SMP Tue Sep 24 18:45:11 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux

`systemctl status dnsmasq.service`
dnsmasq.service

Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit dnsmasq.service is masked.)
   Active: inactive (dead)

This is the result after i run `dnsmasq` as admin

`sudo systemctl enable dnsmasq.service`

When i run this I get the following output:

Synchronizing state of dnsmasq.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable dnsmasq
Failed to enable unit: Unit file /etc/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service is masked.

Does this mean I have to unmask the file?

After boot if I run `journalctl -e --unit dnsmasq.service` Output:

-- Logs begin at Mon 2019-12-23 14:22:16 SAST, end at Mon 2019-12-23 14:27:18 SA
Dec 23 14:22:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: DHCP and DNS server...
Dec 23 14:22:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: DHCP and DNS server.

If I run this command after i run `dnsmasq`I get the same result but the devices now get the correct ip address and can ping the pi and the AP

`dnsmasq --test
dnsmasq: syntax check OK.`

`systemctl cat dnsmasq.service`

`# /run/systemd/generator.late/dnsmasq.service`

`# Automatically generated by systemd-sysv-generator`

`[Unit]`

`Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)`
`SourcePath=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq
Description=LSB: DHCP and DNS server
Before=multi-user.target
Before=multi-user.target
Before=multi-user.target
Before=graphical.target
After=network-online.target
After=remote-fs.target
Wants=network-online.target`

`[Service]`
`Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
SuccessExitStatus=5 6
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq stop`

`systemctl status dnsmasq.service`

`dnsmasq.service - LSB: DHCP and DNS server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/dnsmasq; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2019-12-23 14:47:50 SAST; 3min 34s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 443 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`

`Dec 23 14:47:50 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: DHCP and DNS server...
Dec 23 14:47:50 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: DHCP and DNS server.`

Comment: Run systemctl status dnsmasq.service and add the output to the question. If it's not enabled run also sudo systemctl enable dnsmasq.service which might solve your problem then.

Comment: Updated my answer @jake

Comment: Yes. It is masked by default (forgot about it). So run `sudo systemctl unmask dnsmasq.service && sudo systemctl enable dnsmasq.service` and everything will be fine.

Comment: Thanks Jake ill give it a shot and reboot, maybe add this as an answer

Comment: Ok so it seems as though `dnsmasq` is active when I check its status but new devices connecting to the AP are still getting a random IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `dnsmasq.service` is masked and therefore cannot be enabled.
You have to run these commands to unmaks and enable it:

`sudo systemctl unmask dnsmasq.service && sudo systemctl enable dnsmasq.service`

On my system (raspbian buster) the `systemd-service` looks different than yours:

```
# /lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service
[Unit]
Description=dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
Requires=network.target
Wants=nss-lookup.target
Before=nss-lookup.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid

# Test the config file and refuse starting if it is not valid.
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --test

# We run dnsmasq via the /etc/init.d/dnsmasq script which acts as a
# wrapper picking up extra configuration files and then execs dnsmasq
# itself, when called with the "systemd-exec" function.
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-exec

# The systemd-*-resolvconf functions configure (and deconfigure)
# resolvconf to work with the dnsmasq DNS server. They're called like
# this to get correct error handling (ie don't start-resolvconf if the 
# dnsmasq daemon fails to start.
ExecStartPost=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-start-resolvconf
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-stop-resolvconf


ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Try to reinstall `dnsmasq`:

`sudo autoremove -y --purge dnsmasq && sudo apt install -y dnsmasq`

Then I would try a configuration like this:

```
no-resolv
server=8.8.8.8 # Use Google DNS
interface=eth0 # Use interface eth0
dhcp-range=10.0.0.20,10.0.0.50,255.0.0.255,24h
```

Comment: Sorry jake, it seems as though the service is active when i run `sudo systemctl status dnsmasq.service` but new devices are still getting a random ip address. As soon as i run `sudo dnsmasq` all new devices connected get the correct ip address and allow me to ping the pi and the AP

Comment: question updated

Comment: Another note running `systemctl start dnsmasq.service` doesn't seem to do anything but simply running `dnsmasq` works. Im so confused, it seems as though there may be a broken symlink between the system services and my dnsmasq configuration

Comment: Updated question. I also tried this: i created a bash script that runs `dnsmasq` as root.
I then added the path to the script in the file `rc.local`. This seems to have temporarily solved the problem but I dont think this is best practice

Comment: @ZaydBhyat Do you use raspbian? If so what version?

Comment: I believe its raspbian Buster which is a debian distro. `uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.75-v7+ #1270 SMP Tue Sep 24 18:45:11 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Comment: @ZaydBhyat updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help, ill give this a shot a bit later

Comment: Reinstalling dnsmasq has fixed the problem. Thanks!!

Comment: @ZaydBhyat Please accept the answer. Only accepting an answer will finish your question and it will not pop up again and again for years.