# I need to run the command "sudo service dnsmasq start" on every startup

Tags: networking, terminal, raspberry-pi-os

I need to run the command "sudo service dnsmasq start" on every startup as I'm using my raspberry as a network bridge (from wifi to ethernet) I know the command works but it's hard to start my computer and open Putty and log on to the raspberry and run the command
I need a way to automatically run this command st every startup

I'm a beginner so make it easy, Thanks

Comment: what's the result of `systemctl status dnsmasq` - in particular the `Loaded:` line ... is it enabled? How did you install dnsmasq? `apt install dnsmasq` for me has always resulted in dnsmasq starting on boot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this requires *elevated privileges* (i.e. `sudo`), you can do this by adding it to the `root crontab`. In other words, use `cron` to start this at each boot. You will do this from the command line interface (a terminal):

Once you are logged in, and have the shell prompt, proceed as follows:

```bsh
$ sudo crontab -e
```

You may be prompted to choose an editor - `nano` would be a god choice as it is easiest for beginners.

Once `nano` starts, your screen will show the existing `crontab` for the root user in `nano`. Move the insertion point/cursor to a blank line just below the last line of text. Then, type the following:

```
@reboot sleep 15; /usr/sbin/service dnsmasq start >> /home/pi/dnsmasq-cron.log 2>&1
```

Now save (*`CTRL-o` in `nano`*) and exit (*`CTRL-x` in `nano`*) the `nano` editor. You will get a message that your `crontab` has been created. After that, you will return to the interactive shell & command prompt where you may issue a `reboot` command to test the command.

#### Explanation & alternative to `cron`

What does the `crontab` entry do?

1. `@reboot` means the command(s) following are run once each time your RPi boots
2. `sleep 15` means that `cron` will wait 15 seconds before executing the next command. This gives your system time to get its networking services started before starting `dnsmasq`
3. `/usr/sbin/service dnsmasq start` is the command you supplied to start `dnsmasq`; the full PATH to `service` is used so that `cron` doesn't need to find it.
4. `>> /home/pi/dnsmasq-cron.log 2>&1` ***re-directs*** any output or error messages that you would have gotten in your interactive shell to a file in user `pi`'s home directory. You should examine this file after you `reboot` to make sure it's working properly, and in the event it fails to start.

Finally - this `crontab` you are invoking starts a service. Another way to start this service is to use [`systemd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd); a newer *unified* approach which has its advantages, but may not be as simple as this `crontab` entry. If you're interested, [this Q&A](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106531/dnsmasq-not-starting-on-boot) provides a ***`systemd` way*** to start the `dnsmasq` service.

Comment: I'll try. Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: OMG it works thank you very very much
Now it's easier for me

Comment: @DahamSirimanna: I'm glad it helped. Now, if you don't mind - [please vote](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Ok
I'm new to this stack exchange
Sry